# check instance class by "if" vs. "method"

Tags: php, oop

in php you can't override method so something like this is not possible, because decalaration is not compatible.

```
class Entity
{}

class NotEntity
{}

abstract class Mapper
{
    abstract public function map($data);
}

class EntityMapper extends Mapper
{
    public function map(Entity $data)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The question is: What is better solution?

**IF:**

```
class EntityMapper extends Mapper
{
    /**
     * @param Entity $data
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function map($data)
    {
        if(!$data instanceof Entity) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
$mapper = new EntityMapper();
var_dump($mapper->map(new NotEntity())); //FATAL ERROR: Uncaught Exception
```

**METHOD:**

```
class EntityMapper extends Mapper
{
    /**
     * @param Entity $data
     * @return bool
     */
    public function map($data)
    {
        return $this->mapEntity($data);
    }

    private function mapEntity(Entity $entity)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
$mapper = new EntityMapper();
var_dump($mapper->map(new NotEntity())); //Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to EntityMapper::mapEntity() must be an instance of Entity, instance of NotEntity given
```

**UPDATE**

Shown usage of this object were here just to demonstrate how to get error. Intended usage of this classes is something like this:

```
class Serializer
{
    public function serialize($object, Mapper $mapper)
    {
        return $mapper->map($object);
    }
}

$serializer = new Serializer();
$serializer->serialize(new Entity(),new EntityMapper());
```

Comment: I think it's better with method. But i am gonna wait here for some detailed answers.

Comment: @nbin currently I'm using method too, but only reason is that I don't need to write exception message and still have full detailed reason of error generated by php itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods in PHP can be overriden, but they can't be overloaded. But in your first example you are neither trying to overwrite, nor to overload the method.

What you do is, implementing the method required by the interface (in your case the abstract class) but with a method signature that differs from the constraints given in the interface. That's why PHP complains.

Your first attempt to solve the problem was to implement the `map()` method with it's correct signature. The problem here lies in the methods body. You are explicitly checking for a type. Your API is not only leaking but it's now a liar. Although the method signature states it accepts an argument of any datatype, it is not true because an Exception is thrown when the argument is not of a certain type. **Always watch out for Leaks**.

Since the above attempt was kicked out let's examine the second one.
You are adding a new method `mapEntity` which correctly type hints the wanted datatype. The other method `map()` is there to fullfil the interface.

It seems that this is the only intention of the `map()` method. It is probably not going to be used since you went through the trouble of implementing a dedicated method for that. You implemented a method which is probably not going to be used which breaks the [Interface Seggregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) which simply breaks down to:

> no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use

```
<?php

class Entity
{}

class NotEntity
{}

abstract class EntityMapper
{
    public abstract function map( Entity $data);
}

class DatabaseEntityMapper extends EntityMapper
{
    public function map(Entity $data)
    {
        // Do DB Stuff
        return true;
    }
}

class ArrayEntityMapper extends EntityMapper
{
    public function map(Entity $data)
    {
        // Do Array Stuff
        return true;
    }
}

$em = new ArrayEntityMapper();
var_dump($em->map(new Entity));
```

I would suggest that you introduce a new interface which is a bit more concrete about the type it accepts. Your new abstract class would be the `EntityMapper` which explicitly requires an `Entity` to be passed. The derived classes now comply to the interface.

If you find yourself struggling with descendent of data types consider breaking your interface down and force it to be more descriptive about it's arguments.

Comment: i have updated question with description how i want to use classes to more explain, why can't i throw away that interface and map method. I believe that now it would be ok to use method. Anyway, thanks really much for explanation :)

Comment: You're welcome. Is your Serializer really going to accept multiple types of mappers? If it's specifically for EntityMappers you could typehint those in your Serializer. If it can handle multiple mappers, you could break down your Serializer and have something like an `EntityMapperSerializer` instead. Too much abstraction could also come into your way, so consider the complexity of your project when choosing a proper method.

Comment: Well, there is going to be a lot of mappers, ever model will have one and collection too, well still thanks. I believe that for now this is good solution and if troubles comes in future, i will break it down to smaller classes like you describe :) still thanks, i appreciate your help :)